# Change UTF-8 spaces to RegEx-able spaces

Tags: ruby, regex, encoding, utf-8

I have the following code that parses an HTML document with Nokogiri:

```
td.next_element.text.scan(/\A[^(]+/).first.gsub(/\s+/, " ").strip
```

There is also a `case` statement with a regular expression that has `\s+` and isn't catching anything. I tried to use `strip`, but it did not do anything.

After testing with the `gsub` line above, I figured there was a problem with the way whitespace was encoded. `td.next_element.text[-2].ord` returned not 32 as I had expected, but 160. I realized that my document was in UTF-8 and not ASCII, and that 160 was a non-breaking space.

I should just be able to do this, I thought:

```
case td.text.strip.downcase.gsub(/\xA0|\xC2/, ' ')
```

Problem is, I get

```
Encoding::CompatibilityError 
  (incompatible encoding regexp match (ASCII-8BIT regexp with UTF-8 string)):
```

What do I do?  Also, aren't regular expressions supposed to match all whitespace, not just ASCII?

Comment: What you need to do is set the character encoding of your input data.  I'm not a Ruby programmer, so I don't know the specifics, but there should be some libraries for this.  I did find a related article: http://yehudakatz.com/2010/05/05/ruby-1-9-encodings-a-primer-and-the-solution-for-rails/

Answer (score 4):

Add the comment `#encoding: UTF-8` as the first line of your script; use `/[[:space:]]/` to find Unicode whitespace.